# Importing OpenCV Sample to Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, android-studio-import, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to import a OpenCV sample I got from http://ee368.stanford.edu/Android/OpenCV/ to Android Studio on a windows machine.

However, I'm getting the following error

`* Project CVCamera MSER:C:\AndroidDevelopment\CVCamera_MSER\project.properties:
Library reference ..\..\android-jni could not be found
Path is C:\AndroidDevelopment\CVCamera_MSER\..\..\android-jni which resolves to C:\android-jni`

Any ideas?

EDIT - more info:

I'm using the experimental gradle plugin

```
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha7'
```

And my gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId "co.vispera.moka"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 17
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "mymodule"
//        ldLibs.addAll(['log'])
//        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
//        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
//        stl = '
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1.Maybe your sample's default API version codes are too low.
If you're using Android Studio, try changing build.grade Version codes to newer ones.

example:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

2.If same thing happens, try copying OpenCV libs folder to your project.
Copy OpenCV libs folder,(OpenCVPath/sdk/native/libs)
and paste it inside your app's 'main' folder.
Don't forget to rename it to 'jniLibs'.

Comment: I edited my question to contain my gradle info, it is configures like the way you suggest.
I also have the `OpenCVPath/sdk/native/libs` folder copied under `app/src/main/jniLibs` :/